# R studio optimización

Tags: r, optimización

Estoy teniendo problemas con el código de R para hacer una optimización usando el paquete "desirability". Este es mi cógido:

```
**# Desirability function**

# 1Protein
PRO = function(x)7.95886243386244*x1+9.29564814814816*x2+8.12743386243387*x3-2.70862433862438*x1*x2-2.25005291005295*x1*x3-3.00576719576727*x2*x3-0.939259259259007*x1*x2*x3

# Cost
cost= function(x)0.207407407407407*x1+1.60740740740741*x2+1.60740740740741*x3+9.73544973544982E-02*x1*x2+9.73544973544985E-02*x1*x3-0.016931216931216*x2*x3+0.237037037037024*x1*x2*x3

# Specific volume
Specific=function(x)0.486984126984127*x1+0.43484126984127*x2+0.45484126984127*x3+0.24730158730159*x1*x2-1.55555555555547E-02*x1*x3-1.84126984126985E-02*x2*x3-1.42222222222223*x1*x2*x3


**## Optimization algoritm**

## PROTEIN (Maximize)
dprot=dMax(7.325,9.50)

##COST (Minimize)
dcost=dMin(0.20,1.61)

## SPECIFIC VOLUME (Maximize)
dvol=dMax(0.425,0.523)


**##Calculation of center point projected absorbances**
predOutcomes=c(PRO(c(0,0,0)),cost(c(0,0,0)),Specific(c(0,0,0)))
print(predOutcomes)


PROTEINA=predict(dprot, predOutcomes[1])
COSTE=predict(dcost, predOutcomes[2])
ESPECIFICO=predict(dvol, predOutcomes[3])


overallD <- dOverall(dprot, dcost, dvol)
print(overallD)

predict(overallD, predOutcomes)
```

Cuando hago RUN en el último comando de "predict(overallD, predOutcomes)" me sale el siguiente error:

> predict(overallD, predOutcomes) Error in predict.dOverall(overallD,
> predOutcomes) : the number of columns in newdata must match the number
> of desirability functions

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Bienvenido Maider Lago a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

El manual de la librería desirability contiene una errata. Overall desirability (oD) es,

```
# oD=predict(overallD, predOutcomes) # es incorrecto 
oD=predict(overallD, as.data.frame(matrix(predOutcomes, nrow = 1))) # resuelto
print(oD)
```

Otra manera de calcular el overall desirability sin necesidad de emplear la funcion predict es aplicando la media geometrica de los desirability para cada variable. siendo xD un vector que contiene cada desirability por separado.

```
oD=prod(xD)**(1/length(xD))
print(oD)
```

Obteniendo el mismo resultado